# Silex Route Short-circuiting in before() skips the Route but still executes after() events

Tags: middleware, silex

The [manual](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html) states that the ->before middleware can short-circuit the router like this:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) {
    if (...) {
        return new RedirectResponse('/login');
    }
});
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
$app->post( '/push/{id}', function( $id, Request $request, Application $app ) {
    $app['post.data'] = $request->request->all();
})
->assert( 'id', '[a-f\d]{24}' )
->before(function( Request $request, Application $app ){
    $item = $app['mongodb.maps']->findOne([
        '_id' => new MongoId( $request->get('id') )
    ]);
    if( !$item ) {
        return new RedirectResponse( 'http://test.com', 301 );
    } else $app['mapdata'] = $item;
})
->after(function( Request $request, Response $response, Application $app ){
    if( !isset( $app['post.data'] ) ) {
        return new RedirectResponse( 'http://google.com', 301 );
    }
})
->after(function( Request $request, Response $response, Application $app ){
    if( !isset( $app['post.data'] ) ) {
        return new RedirectResponse( 'http://google.com', 301 );
    }
});
```

The before event fetches the necessary data if assert() succeeds, then passes it into a global variable. Because I return a redirect it skips the route but then executes the after events. In the after events I check if the post data is present which should be created in the route, since the route isn't executed that would throw an error that the post.data key isn't defined. I throw a redirect now in there to finally redirect. But I have to do this in every after() method otherwise I get keys not defined errors. (it never redirects to test.com)

Is this normal? Is there a more solid way to exit at before and skip all other calls?

Comment: I've checked Silex code and I do not see any 'normal' way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation states](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html#short-circuiting-the-controller) (emphasis mine):

> If a before middleware returns a Response object, the request handling is short-circuited (the next middlewares won't be run, nor the route callback), **and the Response is passed to the after middlewares right away**.

So yes, this is the normal behavior.

I don't see an easy way to do what you want either. Without thinking it too much an option could be not to use the default `after` middleware but extend the *Silex\Application* and create your custom `after` middleware that checks if the parameter is present:

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Silex\Application as SilexApp

class MyApp extends SilexApp
{
    public function myAfter($callback, $priority = 0)
    {
        $app = $this;
        $this->on(KernelEvents::RESPONSE, function (FilterResponseEvent $event) use ($callback, $app) {
            if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
                return;
            }
            // Make sure that the callback is called when the pre conditions are met
            if (!empty($app['post.data'])) {
                $response = call_user_func($app['callback_resolver']->resolveCallback($callback), $event->getRequest(), $event->getResponse(), $app);
                if ($response instanceof Response) {
                    $event->setResponse($response);
                } elseif (null !== $response) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException('An after middleware returned an invalid response value. Must return null or an instance of Response.');
                }
            }
            else {
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('http://google.com', 301));
            }
        }, $priority);        
    }
}
```